# Cannot convert from not generic subclass to generic superclass

Tags: java

I'm trying to get interface instance depending on what type T is. Place or something else that extends BaseDictionary.

```
public static <T extends BaseDictionary> IDictionaryDataSource<T> getEntityDataSourceInstance(Class<T> clazz,
        Context cxt) {
    if (Place.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) return (IDictionaryDataSource<T>) new PlaceDataSource(cxt);
            //here some other types, same lines

    return null;
}

public abstract class BaseDictionary{}

public class Place extends BaseDictionary{}

public interface IDictionaryDataSource<T extends BaseDictionary>{}

public abstract class BaseDictionaryDataSource<T extends BaseDictionary> implements   IDictionaryDataSource<T>{}

public class PlaceDataSource extends BaseDictionaryDataSource<Place>{}
```

And I get

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from PlaceDataSource to IDictionaryDataSource<T>
```

or

```
Type safety: Unchecked cast from PlaceDataSource to IDictionaryDataSource<T>
```

if I cast it like above.

Can you explain why do compile error and warning occur?

It will be called here

```
public static <T extends BaseDictionary> DictionaryElementPickerFragment<T> newInstance(Class<T> clazz, Context cxt){
     //somecode here
     fragment.setDataSource(DictUtils.getEntityDataSourceInstance(clazz, cxt));
}
```

I've tried to find answer here and in google but no success.I would appreciate any help.
Now I think like this

> There is no helper method to work around the problem, because the code is fundamentally wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This more concrete example illustrates your problem which is one of *type parameter variance*.

```
void foo(List<String> stringList, Integer anInteger) {
  List<Object> objList = (List<Object>) stringList;
  objList.add(anInteger);  // Violation -- adding an object to a list of strings
                           // could cause someone getting a "String" to get an
                           // Integer stead
}
```

so a `List<String>` is not a `List<Object>` although it is a `List<? extends Object>`.

---

In your specific instance you can't cast

> `PlaceDataSource` to `IDictionaryDataSource<T>`

`PlaceDataSource` *is an* `IDictionaryDataSource<Place>`, but the only thing we know about `<T>` is that it extends `BaseDictionary` which is a super-class of `BaseDictionary`.

So you can cast a `PlaceDataSource` to

1. an `IDictionaryDataSource<Place>` or to
2. an `IDictionaryDataSource<? super Place>` or to
3. an `IDictionaryDataSource<? extends BaseDictionary>`

but not to an `IDictionaryDataSource<T>` because `T` is not guaranteed to be `Place`, and doing so would lead to a mismatch between the actual type parameter `Place` and the formal type parameter `T`.

Answer (score 0):

That is not secure implementation and it is dangerous to cast because (`Place.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)` saves you here):

`T` is a generic type and you're replacing it with definite `Place`.

What if I have

```
public class Home extends BaseDictionary{}
public class HomeDataSource extends BaseDictionaryDataSource<Home>{}
```

And then I invoke `getEntityDataSourceInstance` with `Home` class but get `PlaceDataSource` which cannot be cast to `HomeDataSource` (IDictionaryDataSource) which I expect. So I'll end up having `ClassCastException`.

Comment: so.. how can I implement getting certain DataSource depending on what class variable is? or what parts should I rewrite at all?

Comment: You'll anyway have this warning. But `Place.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)` saves you here so that you don't have situation described above. You can use `@suppressWarnings` annotation

Comment: hmm, maybe I should use some magic pattern or something I don't know?

Comment: Think twice whether you need generic method. Maybe you need it for 1 or 2 classes, jsut implement them then. Other solution would be using `Factory Pattern`. a good example is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/855332/factory-method-pattern-in-java-using-generics-how-to

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `getEntityDataSourceInstance` should be an instance method in the `BaseDictionary` class, not a static method.

A subclass will know which type of `DictionaryDataSource` to create.

Comment: BaseDictionary is just a model with getters and setters, and I was told to do not do this there

Answer (score -3):

Try @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

Comment: nobody talks about errors. there is no error in the code of
a_vasilkov. Generics are verry bad implemented in Java, and often it is the only solution to suppress these nasty warnings about unchecked casts.

Comment: Wrong, Frank. If you don't have any unsafe type warnings, you will never have any `ClassCastException` at runtime. If you don't care about that, just use raw types. But using generics half the time and ignoring the warnings you get about real problems (as in this case; the code does have a bug) is pointless.